# Why is socket.io.engine undefined?

Tags: node.js, sockets, feathersjs

I am using feathersjs and just upgraded to `feathers-authentication-client` using the migration guide. Parts of `feathers-authentication-client` contains `socket.io.engine` which is undefined and throws an error. This is my code and `socket.io.engine` appears in `auth`:

```
import feathers from 'feathers/client';
import hooks from 'feathers-hooks';
import rest from 'feathers-rest/client';
import socketio from 'feathers-socketio/client';
import auth from 'feathers-authentication-client';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import superagent from 'superagent';
import config from './config';

const storage = __SERVER__ ? require('localstorage-memory') : window.localStorage;

const host = clientUrl => (__SERVER__ ? `http://${config.apiHost}:${config.apiPort}` : clientUrl);

const configureApp = transport => feathers()
  .configure(transport)
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(auth({ storage }));

export const socket = io('', { path: host('/ws'), autoConnect: false });

const app = configureApp(socketio(socket));

export default app;

export const restApp = configureApp(rest(host('/api')).superagent(superagent));
```

I have never used `socket.io.engine` and do not understand the relevance in this case. Has anyone used `socket.io.engine` and knows how to help?

### Update  stack trace

```
node_modules/feathers-authentication-client/lib/passport.js:80
[1]         socket.io.engine.on('upgrade', function () {
[1]                         ^
[1] 
[1] TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
[1]     at Passport.setupSocketListeners (node_modules/feathers-authentication-client/lib/passport.js:80:25)
[1]     at new Passport (node_modules/feathers-authentication-client/lib/passport.js:44:10)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/feathers-authentication-client/lib/index.js:36:20)
[1]     at Object.configure (node_modules/feathers/lib/application.js:138:8)
[1]     at configureApp (src/app.js:17:4)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (src/app.js:21:13)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
[1]     at loader (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
[1]     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

> https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication-client/blob/master/src/passport.js

Comment: what specifically is the error you're seeing?  where is it happening?  do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @DanO I added an update and the link to the module.

Comment: Here is the issue discussion: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication-client/issues/12#issuecomment-266526894